# common library for python modules with anaconda

Tags: python, python-import, anaconda

At work we have a common /Lib folder on a network drive where we put modules that anyone in the group can access via Python's import command.  The folder is on everyone's PYTHONPATH.

But I can't access the shared /Lib now that I have replaced my regular python with the Anaconda distribution.  PYTHONPATH is no longer relevant and the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17386880/does-anaconda-create-a-separate-pythonpath-variable-for-each-new-environment) says it is "unnecessary".

How should a small group of people, some using the Anaconda distribution, on Windows machines share common python code?

Comment: import sys 
print sys.path
check your sys.path

Comment: Although I've created a PYTHONPATH environment variable and put the location of the network drive library there, my sys.path is just the folder that I call "print sys.path" from, followed by 'C:\\Miniconda\\python27.zip', 'C:\\Miniconda\\DLLs', etc.  Anaconda ignores PYTHONPATH.

Comment: Anaconda should not be ignoring `PYTHONPATH`. If you use `import os; os.environ["PYTHONPATH"]` is it there?

Comment: os.envirion['PYTHONPATH'] bears no relationship to what I set via the Windows "My computer" GUI before rebooting.  I believe I need to take this up with my ICT department who manage the more "system" aspects of the machine before I can ask a proper question on stackoverflow.  Sorry about wasting your time.

Comment: I am voting to close this question as **Not Reproducible or caused by a Typo** based on the self answer by the author of this question - "*The question arose from a Windows machine with a strange configuration, and is not actually about the behaviour of the Anaconda distribution of Python at all*".

Answer (score 0):

The question arose from a Windows machine with a strange configuration, and is not actually about the behaviour of the Anaconda distribution of Python at all.