# import QGIS modules into Python (Anaconda)

Tags: python, qgis

control QGIS from within Anaconda's Spyder.

I set `PAYTHONPATH` to `C:\Program Files\QGIS Pisa\apps\qgis\bin`, but it still gives this error while import `qgis.core` module:

```
import qgis.core
```

```
ImportError: No module named qgis.core
```

How can I import the module?

Comment: I hope this is not your error **PAYTHON**PATH

Comment: No, there is already PYTHONPATH manager tool in Spyder which helps to select the desired path. I use it.

Comment: I hope you understood Radu's comment: there's a typo in your environment variable `P*A*ython`? If that's not the error, ensure the qgis library is on your path, which you can check by carefully examining `>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.path)`

Answer (score 5):

The answer provided by j08lue works for me. But we also could do this in an Anaconda virtual environment in a specific environment-wide way. So, please try the following steps:

1. Create a conda environment using `conda create -n conda-qgis` and then activate this new environment by using `conda activate conda-qgis`.
2. Install QGIS through conda-forge in the current environment using `conda install -c conda-forge qgis`.
3. Open QGIS by running `qgis`.
4. Use the Python console in QGIS GUI, and run:

   ```
   import sys
   sys.path
   ```

   and you might get system paths like below:

   ```
   'C:/Anaconda3/envs/conda-qgis/Library/./python', 'C:/Users/Guohan/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\\profiles\\default/python', 'C:/Users/Guohan/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\\profiles\\default/python/plugins', 'C:/Anaconda3/envs/conda-qgis/Library/./python/plugins', 'C:\\Anaconda3\\envs\\conda-qgis\\Library\\python', 'C:\\Anaconda3\\envs\\conda-qgis\\Library\\python\\plugins', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Anaconda3\\envs\\conda-qgis\\python39.zip', 'C:\\Anaconda3\\envs\\conda-qgis\\DLLs', 'C:\\Anaconda3\\envs\\conda-qgis\\lib', 'C:\\Anaconda3\\envs\\conda-qgis\\Library\\bin', 'C:\\Anaconda3\\envs\\conda-qgis', 'C:\\Anaconda3\\envs\\conda-qgis\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Anaconda3\\envs\\conda-qgis\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\Anaconda3\\envs\\conda-qgis\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\Anaconda3\\envs\\conda-qgis\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 'C:/Users/Guohan/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\\profiles\\default/python'
   ```
5. Copy all the paths above and get back to the command prompt and run:

   ```
   conda-develop PASTEHERE -n conda-qgis
   ```

   This will create a conda.pth file at the site-package directory, which stores all the environment path variables specified for this conda-qgis environment.
6. Finally, you should be able to use `import qgis` in an Anaconda environment.

Comment: This works. The only thing is I don't have conda-develop, so used "conda develop PASTEHERE -n conda-qgis"

Answer (score 4):

The Python packages shipped with QGIS live in `\path\to\QGIS\apps\Python27\Lib`. So you need to add that to `PYTHONPATH`, rather than `...\qgis\bin`.

It is best to do this on script-basis, rather than system-wide, like so:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\Program Files\QGIS Pisa\apps\Python27\Lib")

import qgis.core
```

But be aware that the QGIS Python packages were likely built for a different version of Python. So things might not work smoothly.

Note: QGIS Python plugins are installed here: `~\.qgis2\python\plugins`, so you might need to `sys.path.append` that too.

Comment: I know this is more than 2yrs old but QGIS 3.x ships with python 3. so it is now optional to work with qgis modules in a python 3 environment.

Comment: Thanks, @Dror, but that is not really related to this question, is it? And Python 3 has been available via OSGeo4W for a long time. QGIS 3 unfortunately does not make it less awkward to link the QGIS / OSGeo4W Python environment to an external Anaconda one. But you can now install QGIS via Anaconda https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/qgis

Answer (score 0):

This is on 2023 and QGIS 3: I couldn't get `import qgis` to work even though I'm not trying to re-use the installation under `C:\Program Files`, but installed a processing copy via Anaconda (`conda install -c conda-forge qgis`; in my case, this is Miniconda3).

Initially, I just got an `ImportError`; this was under my normal Powershell environment. I then opened the **Anaconda Powershell Prompt**, but it didn't work in that either. Executing `conda init powershell` reported that there was nothing to do. I suspected that other tweaks in my PS environment might cause problems, so I then tried the classic (**cmd.exe**-based) **Anaconda Prompt**.

It worked. I then compared the value `sys.path` to the one it had under Powershell and realised that, for some reason, the path `%CONDA_PREFIX%/Library/python` was missing from the latter. I ultimately fixed this by creating a `.pth` file under `%CONDA_PREFIX%/Lib/site-packages` and pasting the missing path into that file. That way it will automatically get appended the `sys.path` every time the environment is activated, and I didn't have to mess with `%PYTHONPATH%`; it's not recommended, because [Anaconda does not use it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31841132/2095725) and when I first tried to use it, [it broke my environment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76382648/2095725).