# (Extreme beginner) Conda env config vars: Potential unintended consequences?

Tags: python, apache-spark, anaconda, environment-variables, environment

I am using Anaconda 3 on Windows 10 x64. I used the instructions [here](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#setting-environment-variables) (see "Setting environment variables") to set environment variables specific to two particular conda environments, one of which is my base environment.

So far this seems to be working great; each environment is giving me the results I want by using the environment variables I want. Not only that, I seem to be able to use them both simultaneously in different applications without any "cross-contamination."

However, I am wondering whether I am creating any potential unintended consequences or learning bad habits by doing this. **What might those unintended consequences or bad habits be, if any?**

**Specifics that may (not) matter:**
My specific application involves the fact that I want to use two python modules:

1. (in my base environment) PySpark (the version that comes with [Spark when I download it from
   the Apache website](https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html))
2. (in another environment) [Databricks-Connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/databricks-connect) (which installs to a folder called "PySpark" and is incompatible with PySpark)

In order to get #1 to work, I have not found any alternative except to set some environment variables, including minimally one called SPARK_HOME pointing to my Spark installation directory, and one called PYTHONPATH including the "Python" subdirectory of SPARK_HOME. I have tried some suggestions (which I'm happy to go into) in order to avoid this but without success (maybe findspark could help me? I tried a little with that). However, once I set those variables using the Windows interface (in particular, I think, the PYTHONPATH one), databricks-connect doesn't work in any environment. That makes sense to me since I'm guessing it is looking for PySpark in SPARK_HOME\Python?

Answer (score 0):

Editing `%PYTHONPATH%` at least sounds bad.

I just broke one of my conda environments by setting a `%PYTHONPATH%` variable (lesson learned: don't do that with conda) via `conda env config vars set PYTHONPATH=<path>`, which prevented me from switching the conda environment back to base except by restarting my shell entirely, because all `conda` commands had broken down.

To rectify, I had to temporarily unset `%PYTHONPATH%` with OS tools; That way basic conda commands started working again. However, the environment broke again every time I reactivated the it, and removing the problematic variable with `conda env config vars unset` didn't work, because the variable was not actually active after I had temporarily unset it.

So to actually make the fix permanent I had to remove the problematic variable from file `%CONDA_PREFIX%/conda-meta/state`, which seems to be the actual config file that stores the variables set with `conda env config`. (I actually just removed the file entirely, because I had nothing else set in there.)

To actually append something to your module path in Anaconda 3, don't use the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, but create a file with `.pth` suffix under `%CONDA_PREFIX%/Lib/site-packages` and paste in that file the paths (one per line, no quotes needed) that you want to automatically append to `sys.path`. That way you won't accidentially break your conda environment.