# Python- Import error of peakutils

Tags: python, anaconda, importerror, pythonpath, peakutils

I am trying to use [peakutils](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PeakUtils) library and have installed that using

```
pip install peakutils
```

but when I attempt to import same in my jupyter notebook, it shows the import error
Before this, I have never faced such an issue. 
I don't have a PYTHONPATH set.

Also, in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17386880/does-anaconda-create-a-separate-pythonpath-variable-for-each-new-environment) the second answer asks for unsetting the python path by

```
unset PYTHONPATH
```

displays

```
'unset' is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I have checked that the package is installed in the environment I am using:

```
(C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3) C:\Users\DELL>activate DAND

(DAND) C:\Users\DELL>pip install peakutils
Requirement already satisfied: peakutils in c:\users\dell\anaconda3\envs\dand\li
b\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in c:\users\dell\anaconda3\envs\dand\lib\si
te-packages (from peakutils)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\dell\anaconda3\envs\dand\lib\si
te-packages (from peakutils)
```

Comment: `unset` is a linux OS command and you are using windows `C:\Users\DELL`

Comment: @hemraj ok, My bad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I navigated through the directory

```
c:\users\dell\anaconda3\envs\dand\lib\site-packages\peakutils
```

and there I didn't find any setup.py, so I proceeded to the source code [here](https://github.com/atjacobs/PeakUtils)
and noticed that I only had the folder peakutils and need to have setup.py along with manifest and readmd.rst. I simply downloaded the files and included them in the folder **site-packages** and then ran

```
python setup.py install
```

in the c:\users\dell\anaconda3\envs\dand\lib\site-packages\ 
directory
and then it worked out

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the problem where I tried to install the library through the Jupyter terminal, but when I went back to my notebook to try 'import peakutils' it still didn't work. So, I tried this three step approach and it worked well.

```
!pip install PeakUtils
!pip install msgpack
!pip install --upgrade pip
```