# Cannot import yaml - anaconda virtual environment with python=2.7

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda, yaml

For one of the projects, I have created anaconda virtual environment.

I install pyyaml, and it appears it is correctly installed:

```
conda list
# packages in environment at /home/<myname>/anaconda3/envs/Alex:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
autobahn                  18.5.1                    <pip>
Automat                   0.6.0                     <pip>
backports.functools-lru-cache 1.5                       <pip>
ca-certificates           2018.03.07                    0  
certifi                   2018.4.16                py27_0  
constantly                15.1.0                    <pip>
Cython                    0.23.5                    <pip>
enum34                    1.1.6                     <pip>
Flask                     1.0.2                     <pip>
hyperlink                 18.0.0                    <pip>
incremental               17.5.0                    <pip>
ipdb                      0.11                      <pip>
ipython                   5.7.0                     <pip>
kiwisolver                1.0.1                     <pip>
libedit                   3.1.20170329         h6b74fdf_2  
libffi                    3.2.1                hd88cf55_4  
libgcc-ng                 7.2.0                hdf63c60_3  
libstdcxx-ng              7.2.0                hdf63c60_3  
matplotlib                2.2.2                     <pip>
ncurses                   6.1                  hf484d3e_0  
numpy                     1.14.3                    <pip>
openssl                   1.0.2o               h20670df_0  
pip                       10.0.1                    <pip>
pip                       10.0.1                   py27_0  
pockets                   0.6.2                     <pip>
protobuf                  3.5.2.post1               <pip>
PyAudio                   0.2.11                    <pip>
pyga                      2.5.1                     <pip>
pysqlite                  2.8.3                     <pip>
pystache                  0.5.4                     <pip>
python                    2.7.15               h1571d57_0  
python-Levenshtein        0.12.0                    <pip>
**pyyaml                    3.12             py27h2d70dd7_1**
```

But when I import yaml into python, it somehow points to the `python=3.6/site-packages`, and I do not know why. It gives syntax error, which is obviously due to the incompatibility of python versions:

```
Python 2.7.15 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, May  1 2018, 23:32:55) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import yaml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  **File "/home/<myname>/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 284**
    class YAMLObject(metaclass=YAMLObjectMetaclass):
```

Look at the starred line, I am using environment where python is set to 2.7, but package is being imported from site-packages of version 3.6.

How do I fix this?

**Edit_1:**
It is only for this package that path resolution is wrong, for other packages, it points to `python=2.7/site-packages`

```
>>> import pyga
>>> pyga.__path__
['/home/<myname>/anaconda3/envs/Alex/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyga']
>>> import pockets
>>> pockets.__path__
['/home/<myname>/anaconda3/envs/Alex/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pockets']
>>> import scipy
>>> scipy.__path__
['/home/<myname>/anaconda3/envs/Alex/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy']
>>>
```

**Edit_2**: Speculation is that somehow it prefers `python=3.6/site-packages` over the other. So I tried this:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/home/<myname>/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages', 

'/home/<myname>/anaconda3/envs/Alex/lib/python27.zip', 

'/home/<myname>/anaconda3/envs/Alex/lib/python2.7', 

'/home/<myname>/anaconda3/envs/Alex/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', 

'/home/<myname>/anaconda3/envs/Alex/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', 

'/home/<myname>/anaconda3/envs/Alex/lib/python2.7/lib-old', 

'/home/<myname>/anaconda3/envs/Alex/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', 

'/home/<myname>/anaconda3/envs/Alex/lib/python2.7/site-packages', 

'/home/<myname>/anaconda3/envs/Alex/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysox-0.3.6a0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg']
```

As you can see, `python3.6/site-packages` appears before `python2.7/site-packages`, so if package is found there, then it will be used. I am not sure this is how it *should* happen, but as a quick hack, is there a way to edit `sys.path` beforehand so that `python2.7/site-packages` will be searched for?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does anaconda create a separate PYTHONPATH variable for each new environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17386880/does-anaconda-create-a-separate-pythonpath-variable-for-each-new-environment)

Comment: @Anthon, IMO this is not a duplicate, as the question gives no direct clue about PYTHONPATH. But if you get enough votes to close it, I dont mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have solved the problem,

entered: (referred form [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17386880/does-anaconda-create-a-separate-pythonpath-variable-for-each-new-environment))

```
unset PYTHONPATH
```

and then

```
>>> import yaml
>>> yaml.__path__
['/home/<myname>/anaconda3/envs/Alex/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yaml']
>>>
```